# The file couldn’t be opened because the text encoding of the contents couldn’t be determined

Tags: html, swift

```
import UIKit
import SwiftSoup

class ViewController: UIViewController {
   
   
    @IBOutlet weak var Ingrediants: UILabel!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        
           let content = try! String(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://google.com")!)
            let doc: Document = try! SwiftSoup.parse(content)
            let tables = try! doc.select("body").first()!
            let rows = try! tables.select("li")
        
        let text = try! tables.html()
        Ingrediants.text = text.HtmlToString
     
         }
   

        
       
     
    }
        
extension String {
    var HtmlToString : String? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
        do{
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil).string
        } catch let error as NSError {print(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

In my swift code, what I am trying to do is turn an html code from a website into a text file or string. I used SwftSoup to first parse the html website, and store the contents in 'table'. All the code for this is located in viewDidLoad. I then proceeded to add an extension that should turn the html into a string which also works. When I used a random website like https://hello.com, the code worked and gave an output. But when I use https://google.com, the code doesn't work. I have also used https://www.google.com/?client=safari but I still get the posted error. Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: FYI - Never use `String(contentsOf:)` with a URL that is not a local file URL, especially from the main thread. Use `URLSession` to load remote content.

Comment: So it would be URLSession(contentsOf: )?

Comment: It's much more involved than that. You need to search on how to load remote content using `URLSession`.

Comment: Aren't local file URLs from you computer? and if I am wrong willURLSession fix my error?

Comment: Yes, local file URLs are files on the local device. I have no idea what in your code is giving an issue about a file being opened. The code you posted make no obvious attempt to open a file. My original point was about your misuse of trying to load remote content into a String using `String(contentsOf:)`. Your app will appear frozen for anyone with a slow Internet connection.